# Java Runnable accessing a class's object

Tags: java, runnable

I have a class that has a job that runs every 10 seconds as shown in the code block below. In Runnable() however, I cannot access the class's objects. I am assuming it has to do with thread-safety in Java.

If I implement Runnable, I will then have to provide a `run()` function. I don't really want to do this. What I want to do is have the class have its own normal functions, but just have this job that runs every X seconds within it, and accesses the class's LinkedList. My run below is contained in the the `scheduleAtFixedRate`, and not in the class itself.

Any ideas?

```
public class MyClass {

    private volatile LinkedList<String> words;

    public MyClass() {
        this.words = new LinkedList<String>();
        this.cleanup();
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // can't access this.words here
                }
            }
        }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

Comment: Note that the `volatile` is most likely wrong here. If you want to access the elements of `words`, then you need to use locking/synchronized or a thread-safe data structure. You would only use `volatile` if you wanted to assign/replace the whole words variable from the Runnable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `MyClass.this.words`, or just `words`.

The `this` reference to an outer class `X` can be accessed using `X.this`. This does not work if the outer class is an anonymous class (which in this case it isn't).

Alternatively, you can use just `words` rather than `something.words` - like with `this`, the compiler will use `X.this` automatically.

Comment: A similar trick I use is just before the anonymous inner class creation do a `final MyClass that = this` and you can access `words` as `that.words`. (Sometimes you see `that` as `parent` or `caller`.)